# ASP.NET FileUpload control in Ajaxified container

Tags: asp.net, ajax, file-upload, updatepanel

I have a `FileUpload` control in a Wizard control.  When I click the `finish` button, I set a breakpoint and I can see the filepath selected in the `FileUpload` control as expected.

However, when I Ajaxify this same Wizard, the value in the `FileUpload` control is always null at this breakpoint, as if a file hasn't been selected.

I know there's a limit where a `FileUpload` control can't keep its value after postback, but I have the breakpoint selected on the postback and would still expect to see the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check this thread: [File uploading in AJAX updatepanel without full postback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/797190/file-uploading-in-ajax-updatepanel-without-full-postback)

Answer (score 0):

You need a full postback to use the `FileUpload` control, try adding the `FileUpload` control to the `PostBackTrigger` section in the `UpdatePanel`.

See: [Problem using the ASP.NET FileUpload control in an UpdatePanel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171840/problem-using-the-asp-net-fileupload-control-in-an-updatepanel)